# Weird issue with Angular Providers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've just started working on Angular2 and I have  my app.module.ts

```
    ...
    ],
providers: [
    {provide:'content',useClass:ContentService}

],
....
```

where I define my literal for my Service Class

And I tried to inject 'content' in my component class like this

```
    export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
constructor( @Inject('content') private contentService ) { }
```

I get an error saying 'No provider for ContentService!'

But when I modify my app.module.ts to

```
    ...
    ],
providers: [
    {provide:'content',useClass:ContentService},ContentService

],
....
```

It works perfectly. For the life of me, I cannot understand this issue.

Comment: Are you trying to mock your service ? If not why `{provide:'content',useClass:ContentService}` and not simply `ContentService` ? As you pointed out your second syntax works because providing only ContentService is the way to go. This expression is not used `{provide:'content',useClass:ContentService}` I think. Also, if your service has already the decorator `@Injectable()`, you don't need to inject it in the constructor  of the component

Comment: I'm new to Angular 2 so there are still stuff I don't completely understand. What I was trying to do was to use content as the place holder for the ContentService. I thought this might help avoid manually importing the service class into my component. I'll work on your suggestion about the @injectable annotation.

Comment: Ok, you should take a look to the service tutorial then : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html